# How can I load a default template into an Angular ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

I'm delving into more advanced Angular routing options using `ui-router`. I've hit a bit of a problem with `<ui-view>`, specifically getting a nested `ui-view` to load with a default template.

I have set up the following routing:

```
  .state('user', {
    url: '/user',
    templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl',
  })
  .state('user.account', {
    url: '/account',
    templateUrl: 'views/account.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl',
  })
  .state('user.profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl',
  })
```

My user page looks like this:

```
<h1>User Home</h1>

<a ui-sref="user.profile">profile</a><br>
<a ui-sref="user.account">manage account</a>

<div ui-view="">
   <div ng-include="profile.html"></div>
</div>
```

In the snippet above I want the `profile.html` template to show by default when the `user.html` page loads.

It seems like it should be possible to do this as it's a basic requirement in most applications to have a default template to display to the user. But I can't get it working and haven't found any obvious solution that doesn't involve creating multiple views inside the `$state` routing which seems like total overkill for something this basic.

I'm just moving from standard `ng-route` to `ui-router` so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Thanks fo rany help!

Comment: Does it work like this: `<div ng-include=" 'profile.html' ">`?

Comment: No luck with that. Just returns a 404. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly navigate to user.profile state on initial go using `$urlRouterProvider.when` block

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/user/profile')
```

Or you could also use `.run` block to load initial page

```
app.run(['$state', function(){
   $state.go('user.profile');
}])
```

Also make sure that user.html should have `ui-view` to render its child state in it.

**views/user.html**

```
<div class="user">
   ...
   <div ui-view><div>
   ..
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes, the first suggestion works but just wondering is this only way to achieve it?It's just that when trying to apply to nested views within other nested views it gets very confusing fast and clogs up the top of the `$stateProvider` config block. If there is no other less cumbersome solution I'll upvote your answer. Cheers for the help!